# Android Error Fatal Exception at main and AsyncTask #2

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have no idea why I am getting this error on my logcat. Once i run my app, it crashes halfway.

This is my AsyncTask code:

```
OnClickListener addMovieButtonClicked = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(mvidEditText.getText().length()!= 0){
            AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>addMovieTask =
                    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>(){
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object... params){
                    addMovie();
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(AddMovie.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            };
            addMovieTask.execute((Object[]) null);
        }else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddMovie.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null);
            builder.show();
        }
    }
};
```

This is the error message at logcat:

[image: first part error]

[image: second part error]
[image: third part error]

Updated with the addMovie() code:

```
private void addMovie(){
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    if(getIntent().getExtras()== null){
        databaseHandler.insertRow(
                mvidEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvtitleEditText.getText().toString(),
                mvtypeEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvstoryEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvratingEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvlanguageEditText.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(mvruntimeEditText.getText().toString()));
    }else {
        databaseHandler.updateRow(rowID,
                mvidEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvtitleEditText.getText().toString(),
                mvtypeEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvstoryEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvratingEditText.getText().toString(), 
                mvlanguageEditText.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(mvruntimeEditText.getText().toString()));

    }
}
```

This is the DatabaseHandler code for insertRow():

```
public long insertRow(String mvkey, String mvtitle, String mvtype,
        String mvstory, String mvrating, String mvlanguage, int mvruntime){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_KEY, mvkey);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, mvtitle);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, mvtype);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORY, mvstory);
    initialValues.put(KEY_RATING, mvrating);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LANGUAGE, mvlanguage);
    initialValues.put(KEY_RUNTIME, mvruntime);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}
```

I am sorry for the screenshot, but thats the only way to show the error. I am a beginner on Android app development. Thank you.

Comment: where is `addMovie();` code?? post it..

Comment: @MD i have post it. Can you please help me on it...

Comment: just remove toast from onpostexecute

Comment: @raj it still seems the same

Comment: can you tell which line of code throwing error.

Comment: @bharat actually i have posted all the logcat errors as an image. But now once i checked it shows 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: @bharat this error was at the DatabaseHandler insertRow()
`at com.example.moviemanager.DatabaseHandler.insertRow(DatabaseHandler.java:84)`

Comment: 1. Make sure all your EditText's are initialized and 2. Inside `insertRow()` method db is initialized while calling constructor of `DatabaseHandler()`.

Comment: I have solve it actually @bharat thanks for your help. I did some mistake on my insertRow()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accidentally changed my pulic void function at the insertRow(). So what i did was i changed my below code

```
public long insertRow(String mvkey, String mvtitle, String mvtype,
    String mvstory, String mvrating, String mvlanguage, int mvruntime){
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(KEY_KEY, mvkey);
initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, mvtitle);
initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, mvtype);
initialValues.put(KEY_STORY, mvstory);
initialValues.put(KEY_RATING, mvrating);
initialValues.put(KEY_LANGUAGE, mvlanguage);
initialValues.put(KEY_RUNTIME, mvruntime);

return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

this is my updated and working code:

```
public void insertRow(String mvkey, String mvtitle, String mvtype,
        String mvstory, String mvrating, String mvlanguage, int mvruntime){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_KEY, mvkey);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, mvtitle);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, mvtype);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORY, mvstory);
    initialValues.put(KEY_RATING, mvrating);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LANGUAGE, mvlanguage);
    initialValues.put(KEY_RUNTIME, mvruntime);

    open();
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    close();
}
```